# How can I grep a column of a data frame in R and return multiple subsets?

Tags: r, loops, filter, dplyr

I am working with a pretty messed up data set and I would like to grep a column using key words, create a subset, and the loop to the next key word(s). For example, I would like to grep the words "banana|apple" and then create a subset called "fruits", then search the words "brocolli|carrot" and create a subset called "vegitables".

| item | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | $0.50 | 10 |
| Banana | $0.50 | 5 |
| bananas | $0.50 | 5 |
| ripe bananas | $0.50 | 3 |
| apple | $1.00 | 5 |
| green apple | $1.10 | 5 |
| broccoli | $1.15 | 7 |
| carrot | $1.50 | 10 |
| Carrots | $1.50 | 10 |

*I was able to create subsets using these lines of code*

```
fruits <- filter(df, grepl("banana|apple",ProcedureDisplay, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE))

vegitables <- filter(df, grepl("broccoli|carrot",ProcedureDisplay, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE))
```

*But I was wondering if there were a way I could set up a reference table and loop through using something like this:*

```
for(i in 1:nrow(ref_table)){

  filter(df, grepl(i,ProcedureDisplay, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE))

}
```

`ref_table`

| subset | search keys |
| --- | --- |
| fruits | "banana","apple" |
| vegitables | "broccoli","carrot" |

*so the `fruits` output should look like this*

| item | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | $0.50 | 10 |
| Banana | $0.50 | 5 |
| bananas | $0.50 | 5 |
| ripe bananas | $0.50 | 3 |
| apple | $1.00 | 5 |
| green apple | $1.10 | 5 |

*and `vegitables` look like this*

| item | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| broccoli | $1.15 | 7 |
| carrot | $1.50 | 10 |
| Carrots | $1.50 | 10 |

*The reason I want to have a reference table is because in the real world application that I'm using this for, there are multiple search keys and they are continuously updated. And instead of searching through multiple lines of code and trying to read/interpret/update the commands, it would be better for other users to simple update a table which the r script could reference and use the grep function.*

Comment: Do you match `ripe bananas` or `green apple`

Comment: yes, so anything that contains the word `banana` or `apple`

Comment: It is not clear from the input and expected, whther the expected is the output from your input

Comment: I just edit the original post to show what the output should look like, does this help?

Comment: Please provide example data that can be copied and pasted (e.g. as the output from ```dput()```).

Comment: I think people have already answered your question but it might be worth it to check the rcorpora package or something like it. This package has a list of words that fit into  food categories.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl`

```
 subset(df1, grepl('banana|apple', item, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop over a list of values first make that list:

```
keys <- list( fruits = "banana|apple", vegetables = "broccoli|carrot")
```

then use `lapply` with akrun's answer:

```
lapply(keys, function(x) subset(produce, grepl(x, item, ignore.case = T)))
```

Or, if you prefer a dataframe for the keys, you can do this:

```
keys2 <- data.frame(fruits = c("banana", "apple"), vegetables = c("broccoli", "carrot"))

lapply(keys2, function(x) subset(produce, grepl(paste0(x, collapse = "|"), item, ignore.case = T)))
```

output looks like this:

```
$fruits
          item price quantity
1       banana $0.50       10
2       Banana $0.50        5
3      bananas $0.50        5
4 ripe bananas $0.50        3
5        apple $1.00        5
6  green apple $1.10        5

$vegetables
      item price quantity
7 broccoli $1.15        7
8   carrot $1.50       10
9  Carrots $1.50       10
```

data:

```
produce <- structure(list(item = c("banana", "Banana", "bananas", "ripe bananas",       
"apple", "green apple", "broccoli", "carrot", "Carrots"), price = c("$0.50", 
"$0.50", "$0.50", "$0.50", "$1.00", "$1.10", "$1.15", "$1.50",
"$1.50"), quantity = c(10, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 7, 10, 10)), row.names = c(NA,     
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse option.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

filter(df, str_detect(item, regex('banana|apple', T)))

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   item         price quantity
#   <chr>        <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 banana       $0.50       10
# 2 Banana       $0.50        5
# 3 bananas      $0.50        5
# 4 ripe bananas $0.50        3
# 5 apple        $1.00        5
# 6 green apple  $1.10        5

filter(df, str_detect(item, regex('broccoli|carrot', T)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   item     price quantity
#   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 broccoli $1.15        7
# 2 carrot   $1.50       10
# 3 Carrots  $1.50       10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main_df=structure(list(item = c("banana", "Banana", "bananas", "ripe bananas", 
"apple", "green apple", "broccoli", "carrot", "Carrots"), price = c("$0.50", 
"$0.50", "$0.50", "$0.50", "$1.00", "$1.10", "$1.15", "$1.50", 
"$1.50"), quantity = c(10L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

reference_df = structure(list(subset = c("fruits", "vegitables"), search_keys = c("banana,apple", 
"broccoli,carrot")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Its ideal for the `reference_df` to be tidy version i.e long form.

```
library(fuzzyjoin) #install the package in case not available.
library(tidyr) #install the package in case not available.

main_df %>% regex_inner_join(reference_df %>%
                          tidyr::separate_rows(search_keys, sep = ","),
                        by = c("item" = "search_keys"))
```

`separate_rows` will make the data long form using the comma as separator and later joined back to the `main_df` based on the 2 key columns (item,search_keys)

The final result it this.

```
          item price quantity     subset search_keys
1       banana $0.50       10     fruits      banana
2      bananas $0.50        5     fruits      banana
3 ripe bananas $0.50        3     fruits      banana
4        apple $1.00        5     fruits       apple
5  green apple $1.10        5     fruits       apple
6     broccoli $1.15        7 vegitables    broccoli
7       carrot $1.50       10 vegitables      carrot
```